# SSH attack by IP that is blocked

Tags: security, centos, ssh, iptables

I run a CentOS 5.7 64bit server which has a strange issue.

While I was watching my logs at `/var/log/secure` I noticed that one strange IP was trying to connect to ssh with a lot of strange usernames.

Output of the log: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3uYjPrLL

I run fail2ban which had already blocked this IP, and I also blocked this IP again manually via iptables.

Running `iptables -n -L` I got this output:

```
Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  50.115.166.129       0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

So the block is in place. Iptables is also running, and I have blocked many IP's via iptables already, and those blocks are all working fine.

But somehow this IP is able to get to my machine. Any idea how this is possible?

Comment: Perhaps the `fail2ban-SSH` chain is never being invoked, or is invoked at the wrong stage of processing.  We'll need to see the output of `iptables -L -n -v` to say anything useful.

Comment: This is the output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kxYGc6Gs

Comment: The top of the output is missing, so we can't be sure that it starts with rule 1.  Could you ensure that **all** the output of the iptables command makes it into your pastebin?  And can you confirm what port you're running sshd on?

Comment: I have updated the pastebin file, now shows full output. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kxYGc6Gs its a couple thousand lines as I recently had to block a whole bot network that was flooding my site.

Comment: ssh is running on port 2222

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your `fail2ban-SSH` chain is being applied to traffic to port 22, which isn't where your sshd is listening.  So fail2ban picks up the failures from the auth logs, and correctly updates the refusal chain.  But ssh traffic is never sent to that chain, so your malfeasor, who is now blocked from talking to port 22, is still able to talk to sshd on 2222.

Assuming you're using standard CentOS `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, you need to change the line in the `filter` section that currently says something like

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j fail2ban-SSH
```

to say

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j fail2ban-SSH
```

As for your manual drop, you have added it **after** the lines that say

```
 689M  126G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

and

```
 0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2222 state NEW
```

so it will simply never get invoked to limit new traffic to port 2222, or subsequent packets in any such connection, as those have already been permitted.  The order of rules is **vital** in iptables, because first dispositive match wins.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the default ssh port in the jail.conf file, that worked.